# Github redirects me to “Sign out of GitHub” when I delete my account

Tags: account-management, github

I followed the delete account instruction on Github, and when I do the “delete account” action, Github always redirects me to a sign out page.

> Sign out of GitHub?
>   You can always sign back in at any time.

Any even after a day or two, I can still sign in with this accout.

How can I permanently delete my github account?